# Python socket recv() hangs due to hardware?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, blocking, recv

I'm running into troubles with recv() function in python socket. The clients runs on their own threads (or processes) and each client has a corresponding listening thread on the server as well. There are frequent message sending and receiving on both clients and server. Sometimes the code works fine and terminates. But there are also occasions where the code just hangs on recv().

An example is when server has already received something and does send(b"OK") to the client to indicate that it has indeed received the message and client does recv(2) after sending the previous message

Server.py

```
...  # some previous code
server.recv(1024)  # This works fine
server.send(b"OK")  <-- blocks
```

Client.py

```
...  # some previous code
client.send(a)  # Assume a is 1024 bytes, this works fine
client.recv(2)  <-- blocks
...  # Codes that triggers further actions on client and server
```

And the whole process just hangs on that recv(). All sockets are set to be blocking so it has to be the problem that the message is not received properly so that further codes are blocked from that call.

But this only happens sometimes not always so I know the overall logic and process actually works fine. Is this a problem with the hardware allocating memory/buffer of that size being slow? Is there a way to solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the previous `recv` call didn't receive the OK?

Comment: @user253751 yes I'm pretty sure. I keep the code in the fashion such that both server and client perform send() and recv() alternatively so that it doesn't mis-receive messages

Answer (score 0):

Try using `sendAll()` to be sure that the entire payload is sent by both server and client.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately I have tried sendAll() and the same behaviour would appear from time to time. :-(

Comment: Well, if you tell me that the problem appears from time to time, it's likely a sync issue. Are you sure that your code doesn't end up with a `send()` sent before the other party would enter in `recv()`? If the code isn't huge and private you could share the code so that we can try it on our machines and debug it.

Comment: Hi, I just checked again and think there isn't such case that I put several `send()` together and causing mis-receiving. And sorry I think I can't share the code since it's pretty chunky and also being a private project :-( I would love to hear about the "sync issue" tho. What do you mean by it?

Comment: What I mean by "sync" problem is that the server sends the data before the client starts listening to it (or the opposite). Without code I can't assure it, but if you tell me that the client and the server sometimes end up fine, while other times they don't it's very likely that the problem is the timing between the two entities.

Comment: A followup on this problem. Just solved it by reducing the buffer size in a function used for receiving larger information. Not exactly sure how that resulted in the above problem but my guess is it might have problems receiving relatively smaller messages using that function and gets blocked. But anyway, the "sync issue" hint made me think about it so thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you are using TCP, you could be running into the Nagle buffering algorithm.  Its purpose is to improve efficiency by collecting small packets into a single larger one.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think that could be the case but I'm gonna try it out first (by sending a "bigger" confirmation message each time). But on the other hand, if that's the case, how come it behaves differently each time I run it and is there a size threshold that would definitely trigger the socket to send the message in the python implementation?

Comment: Hi, I just implemented this and sadly it doesn't seem to solve the problem.